# postgis query performance

Tags: postgis, sql, performance

The db structure is more or less like this and can't be modified. I can only add some indexes but can't set for example foreign keys:

```
    CREATE TABLE adresspoint
(
  id character varying(3999) NOT NULL,
  "position" geometry(PointZ,25832)
  CONSTRAINT pk_adresspoint PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE INDEX adresspoint_idx_position
  ON adresspoint
  USING gist
  ("position");

CREATE TABLE house
(
  id character varying(3999) NOT NULL,
  adresspointid character varying(3999),
  CONSTRAINT pk_house PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE INDEX house_idx_adresspointid
  ON house
  USING btree
  (adresspointid COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

I have query like that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT house.id 
FROM house 
   LEFT JOIN adresspoint ON adresspoint.id = house.adresspointid 
             AND st_contains(st_makeenvelope('562827','6326412','563365','6326590',25832),adresspoint.position)
OFFSET 0 LIMIT 100
```

and it runs very quickly (100 ms) but when I change it to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT house.id 
FROM house 
  LEFT JOIN adresspoint ON adresspoint.id = house.adresspointid 
        AND st_contains(st_makeenvelope('562827','6326412','563365','6326590',25832),adresspoint.position)
WHERE adresspoint.id is not null -- ***change is here***
OFFSET 0 LIMIT 100
```

It runs very slowly (like 100 times slower).

I wonder what is the reason behind it and is there any way I can optimize it? I have indexes on position, ids etc.

Comment: Have you analyzed the query using EXPLAIN ANALYZE [your query here]? Maybe that will already give you the answer you're looking for. At least you'll see which indices are used and what part of your query takes how much time.

Comment: I would try INNER JOIN. Then you do not need to test `adresspoint.id is not null`